# job-launching-gateway and persistent queue

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm working on a project with spring-boot, spring-batch and spring-integration.

I have already configured spring-integration to start a spring-batch job when a new message arrives.

I send a message to the spring-integration channel attached to the JobLaunchingGateway and, for each message, the JobLaunchingGateway try to starts a new TaskExecutor.

Let the channel be backed by a persistent queue ( ActiveMQ as example ) 
Let the task-executor pool-size be equal to 2.

I would like to configure the system so that when the executor pool-size is already used the new messages are not consumed by the JobLaunchingGateway but remains on the persistent queue.

Is it possible? Is there any best practices.

Any feedback will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a queue limit to the TE and use the `CallerBlocksPolicy' for the`RejectedExecutionHandler`.

However, in the event of a failure, you will lose the task(s) in the queue.

It's generally better to use a message-driven channel, set the concurrency to two and run the jobs on the listener container thread rather than using a TE to run the job.

The additional benefit is if the job fails, or the machine crashes, you won't lose that request. Once you hand over to the TE, the message is gone from the queue.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response.  
The second way is exactly what I would like to implement because I don't want to lose anything in case of crash.  

But, what do you mean with "run the job on the listener container"?   

Are you suggesting to run the job within an implementation of MessageDelegate and pass this MessageDelegate to the DefaultMessageListenerContainer through a MessageListenerAdapter?   

And what do you think about a "batch-int:job-launching-gateway" that use a jobLouncher with a SyncTaskExecutor ?

Comment: Just don't use a task executor at all and the job will run on the channel's listener container thread. The framework will take care of everything for you. The `SubscribableJmsChannel` has a container; set its concurrency as you desire and wire the job launching gateway to it directly. If you are still having trouble understanding, edit your question with your current configuration so someone can guide you.